# How to flag a shared todo list in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am quite new to Django.

Basically I am working on a complex checklist app. This checklist contains various checkpoints. A checklist can be assigned to a client but it's not directly related to a client, instead it's assignment is based on some attribute filter of checkpoint.

```
class Checkpoint(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)   
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    value_chain = models.ForeignKey(Valuechain)
    manadatory = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pending = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Client(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('client name', max_length=100)
    duns = models.IntegerField('duns number', max_length=9, unique=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    value_chain = models.ForeignKey(Valuechain)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Suppose a checklist contains 10 checkpoint. Every checkpoint have two attributes, message and value chain, which are foreign key to client model as well.

Given 4 checkpoints out of 10 have message value "MA" and value chain value "VCA" and client selects same values of message and value chain then checklist of that particular client will have only these 4 checkpoints in it. In short it's filtered list based on these attribute's values.

It implies any other client who selects same value for these two attribute will also have same checklist.

The goal is to mark checkpoint as done, but this should be for only one client, under whose checklist we are marking, not for any other client.

But when I am rendering a checklist for client, based on attribute filter and updating any of checkpoint as done, it's updating that checkpoint globally. which I don't want.

SO basically this is where I am stuck and seeking some guidance here. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey fusionstrings, seeing as nobody has answered, I think it would help to show code examples of what you're doing. Show what you are doing in code and which line is causing problems (updating globally). We all speak django but not django in words as much.

Comment: My problem is more related to logic, django specific logic to be precise. I am giving you similar situation, question paper app for a school. 

Suppose there is a table of questions. Each question has class and subject associated with it. A student can decide to attempt questions by filtering questions based on class and subject. Now I am having tough time to flag a question under student name which he has attempted. Of course  a different student can attempt same question set but we don't want to mark certain question done for all the students whether or not they have attempted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but it seems to me that you'll need a many-to-many field for done Checkpoints in Client (or in some related field which is unique
to each client).  That will permit you to associate each checkpoint as 'done' by adding it to the client's 'done' many-to-many field.

If you need each Checkpoint to have unique attributes for each client, then you instead need to instantiate new Checkpoint instances for each done checkpoint, and bind it to the Client instance with a foreign key field in Checkpoint, pointing to Client.